# Creating a Unique PostgreSQL Index that Contains Operations

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I would like to create a unique PostgreSQL index that contains operations.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_data ON table (name, color)
```

The operation that I would like to add is "num & new_num = 0", where num is an existing column and new_num is a value to be inserted.

Is this possible?

**Update:** Here's more detail regarding what I want to do.

Database:

```
name    color    num
one     red      5
two     green    5
one     red      8
```

What I want to do is to prevent the case where an entry is not unique, like:

New entry 1: name = one, color = red, num = 1.

We have matching names and colors and the first num check results in 101 & 001 = 1, this New entry 1 is not unique, and should be rejected, however, if the number was changed to 2.

New entry 2: name = one, color = red, num = 2

Now we have matching names and colors.  For the num in all name/color matches 101 & 010 = 0, and 1000 & 0010 = 0, so we have a unique entry.

Comment: That sounds more like a check constraint rather than an index.

Comment: If it can be done using a check constraint, i'd take that too.  I just don't know whether it's possible to check.  Something like this: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_ft ON base.ft (ft_date DESC, ft_num, sq) WHERE (ver = true);, except check the incoming value against values in the db.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is hard to guess what you are after. Add a test case if you don't find the right terms to describe your intentions.

Comment: You want to test new_num against all existing values in the column "num"?

Comment: I'm wondering if you're really looking for an exclusion constraint.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I'm pretty sure an exclusion constraint alone won't work here. I think the OP might have to go with a transformation that lets him use one of the geometric operators. The bit_ops operator class won't work, because bitwise "and" isn't a member.

Comment: To me, this is starting to look like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: As I stated in my comment above, I will take any solution.  Now that the issue is stated more clearly, feel free to recommend an alternative solution.  As it stands the index is only on name and color.  I posted here hoping to find a solution where I could combine the checking of num, but maybe that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a project and a half.  It doesn't look like there is a very easy way to do this, and yet with PostgreSQL anything is possible.  I think you want an exclude constraint using GIST.  Unfortunately, that exclude constraint is not going to be an easy one to do since there are no easy types that support this.

Your basic solution I think is going to have to involve:

1. A cast to a suitable data type (presumably bit(n))
2. Sufficient operators to allow GiST indexes of bit(n). T his means you have to build functions and operators for all GiST operation classes, create operator families, etc.
3. Create an exclude constraint using your operations.

This will not be easy and it will be complicated but with some effort and dedication it is possible.  I would expect one to two hundred lines of code will be involved in doing it.  You'd probably want to write unit tests too.